# Wicket Submit BehaviorListener after RestartResponseExeption and Session replacement

Tags: session, behavior, wicket-6

I have a AjaxFallbackLink to add a product into the wishlist of a customer. When a guest clicks the Link he is redirected to the login page with a RestartResponseAtInterceptPage. After successful login he returned to the first Page. But the URL contains the IBehaviorListener of my "add to wishlist" Link and every Ajax Link does nothing except to reload the page with no changes. I think the problem is the incorrect match of Page instance and BehaviorListener instance because my Page started with instance 1 and returned with instance 4 from Login Page. Everything works when the guest is already logged in.
How can i remove the illegal URL parameter or call the right Link callback to add the product to wishlist after successful login?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the following, in YourApplication#init() add:

```
getPageSettings().setCallListenerInterfaceAfterExpiry(true)
```

You can override it per Page if you don't want to enable it globally, see `org.apache.wicket.Component#canCallListenerInterfaceAfterExpiry()`

Comment: I Test this tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I use Wicket version 6 and there doesn't exist the method Component#canCallListenerInterfaceAfterExpiry(). Exist a way to workaround this?

Comment: No. This is an improvement in 7.x, I'm afraid.